# How to select Scrapy's xpath one before last element of a list <li>?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am scraping an e-commerce website (ex. link: https://elektromarkt.lt/namu-apyvokos-prekes/virtuves-ir-stalo-reikmenys/keptuves). I am facing an issue while using pagination, the page does not have a specific tag or attribute for next page button (at the bottom of the website) and I realised I am not getting all the data. How may I select the one before last

element using xpaths?
Before I tried to find out which of the elements it is but I realised some product lists have only 1-3 pages which makes them invalid.

This is my parsing function:

```
def parse_items(self,response):
    for href in response.xpath(self.getAllItemsXpath):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse_main_item, dont_filter=True)
        
    nexter_page = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[12]/a/@href').extract_first()
    if nexter_page is None:
        next_page = response.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[10]/a/@href').extract_first()
        url = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
    else: 
        url = response.urljoin(nexter_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But the page number is changing and showing on the browser's url and You can make the pagination from start_urls using for loop.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls=['https://elektromarkt.lt/namu-apyvokos-prekes/virtuves-ir-stalo-reikmenys/keptuves?page='+str(x)+'' for x in range(1,3)]
        
    def parse(self, response):
       print(response.url)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process =CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl()
    process.start()
```

**Output:**

```
https://elektromarkt.lt/namu-apyvokos-prekes/virtuves-ir-stalo-reikmenys/keptuves?page=1
https://elektromarkt.lt/namu-apyvokos-prekes/virtuves-ir-stalo-reikmenys/keptuves?page=2

 'downloader/response_status_count/200':
```